# PayPal onApprove not calling ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to add a boolean to the database when the payment is successful.

```
  <script>
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: '0.01'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      $.ajax({
        url: "includes/payment_db.php",
        success: function(data) {
          alert('Successfully called');
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
          alert('Exception:', exception);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The ajax function is not working. It doesn't show any error or success message.

Answer (score 3):

This type of payment flow should not be used. Do not capture on the client side and then record information in your database.

Instead, use a proper server-side integration that captures directly from the server, so you have an immediate API response of success or failure, and are not dependent on the client to notify you of what happened.

To accomplish this, create two routes on your server, one for "Create Order" and one for "Capture Order", suing the v2/checkout/orders REST API (first use your client-id and secret to obtain an access_token)

Pair those two routes with the following JavaScript for approval: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I can't undertstand how it's.

Comment: como o que é o quê?

Comment: onde é que vou chamar a minha função do php no server integration

Comment: You need to create two NEW routes. `includes/create_payment.php` and `includes/capture_payment.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` for example -- or whatever works for you.